# MySql order by multiple columns sorting NULL entries at first

Tags: mysql, sorting, isnull

I've a table as shown in the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2169f/2).

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


 INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `name`, `description`, `priority`, `created_date`) VALUES
('1', 'John', 'kasdjkaksdj', 3, '2018-07-12 07:37:25'),
('2', 'Doe', 'updations', 1, '2018-07-12 08:56:27'),
('3', 'Matt', 'sdasd', NULL, '2018-07-12 09:09:08'),
('4', 'Jiss', 'vghjgfghj', 1, '2018-07-13 12:33:19'),
('5', 'Noel', 'sdfsdf', NULL, '2018-07-13 12:33:29');
```

The `priority` column is `NULL` by default. User can specify any integer values to this column. I want to sort the table based on the `priority asc` and for rest of the records (which have NULL priority) sort by `created_date asc`.

I tried with the query

```
SELECT * FROM `test` ORDER BY priority, created_date
```

**Result :**

> ```
> id    name    description priority    created_date
>
> 3     Matt    sdasd        (null)      2018-07-12T09:09:08Z
>
> 5     Noel    sdfsdf       (null)      2018-07-13T12:33:29Z
>
> 2     Doe     updations     1          2018-07-12T08:56:27Z
>
> 4     Jiss    vghjgfghj     1          2018-07-13T12:33:19Z
>
> 1     John    kasdjkaksdj   3          2018-07-12T07:37:25Z
> ```

But this is showing priorities with `NULL` values first followed by records sorted by priority.

**Excepted result:**

> ```
> id    name    description priority    created_date
>
> 2     Doe     updations     1          2018-07-12T08:56:27Z
>
> 4     Jiss    vghjgfghj     1          2018-07-13T12:33:19Z
>
> 1     John    kasdjkaksdj   3          2018-07-12T07:37:25Z
>
> 3     Matt    sdasd        (null)      2018-07-12T09:09:08Z
>
> 5     Noel    sdfsdf       (null)      2018-07-13T12:33:29Z
> ```

Can anyone help me to find the correct query. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code

```
SELECT * FROM `test` ORDER BY ISNULL(priority) ,priority, created_date
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e32b23/5)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is working fine, but there is only one issue that is :

You need to just add "name" in after ORDER BY:

for reference : go to [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2169f/8)